# Set-cookie not working

Tags: ajax, wcf, cookies

I have a svc service running on **crm.mch.be**. On a specific request it returns a response with this headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2015 14:20:56 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=800196267D28CE...; Path=/; Domain=crm.mch.be
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

The request is made through an (jQuery) ajax call made from **wip.myserver.local**.

The problem is the cookie isn't set.

When the ajax call complete I redirect (`window.location.href = ...`) the user to the website **crm.mch.be**. But it doesn't have the cookie set.
And prior the redirection, if I list all my browsers cookies, this cookies doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Isn't good for credentials/cookies http exchanges in browsers.
One have to be more restrictive and specify the domain.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: wip.myserver.local
```